# Using jq to turn array of objects in to a flat array

Tags: json, jq

Using jq, I'd like to to flatten a (nested) array of objects to an array of strings.

e.g. given the input

```json
{
  "message-id": 1,
  "result": {
    "info": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "foobar",
      "route": [
        {
          "nodeid": 1,
          "nodename": "name-1"
        },
        {
          "nodeid": 2,
          "nodename": "name-2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to turn it in to

```json
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "route": [
    "name-1",
    "name-2"
  ]
}
```

But am struggling with flattening the `route` node - getting no further than

```
 .result.info | { name: .name, route: .route }
```

which essentially leaves the route node unchanged. This is probably straightforward, but nonetheless currently eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it that's pretty close to your attempt.

```jq
.result.info
| {name} + {route: .route|map(.nodename)}
```

Example output:

```json
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "route": [
    "name-1",
    "name-2"
  ]
}
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/w-Z6Y1tpJdp).

Comment: Excellent - thank you. I think all the answers worked, but this is the one I ended up going with as it's the one I understood best. Thanks again.

Comment: (bizarrely this fails if there is only one route on real - more complex - data, but is fine in the crude test I wrote above - perhaps too simple, I'll see if I can construct a more representative example)

Comment: EDIT: Please ignore that. Different input data caused it to trip up, not unexpectedly, apologies!

Comment: @gdt We can only address the issue presented to us.¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation that is the same as your attempt, plus one step to modify `route`:

```
.result.info
| .route |= map(.nodename)
| {name, route}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear, what determines on which level you want to collect (e.g. you are using `.result.info` literally), and which fields to collect into (or why `.id` doesn't get an empty array), but this might help you along your path:

With `..` you can recursively scan the document tree, `strings` filters for strings, and `[…]` collects the results into an array. Also, I've used `map_values` to replace the values of all fields in the object. Feel free to change this to just the fields you need. You may, for instance, remove empty arrays or change one-item array to the one string itself.

```bash
.result.info | map_values([.. | strings])
```

```json
{
  "id": [],
  "name": [
    "foobar"
  ],
  "route": [
    "name-1",
    "name-2"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WFs-Le8M_Sg)